# Specifying only text color

Tags: css, colors, font-face

I have an element whose `background-color` and `border-color` are specified, and within that element, I have another element, which I want to specify only the text color  and have the background and border colors inherited. If I use `color` on it, It looks like the background and border colors are changed to that color also. Is there a way to specify only the text color?

Comment: any fiddle available to demonstrate the problem??

Comment: Seriously, you have >62k rep; you must have anticipated requests for code to repro your problem..

Comment: @KyleSevenoaks You are wrong. AlexDom's answer can tell you about it.

Comment: My apologies; I was pointing out that you clearly have experience in using this site, and so you should have known to provide relevant code in your question to demonstrate your problem. For further advice, please see the [MCVE guidance](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/).

Comment: @DavidThomas Thanks for pointing that. But I thought it was clear enough from my words in the question.

Comment: Descriptions of code, and code itself, often have some profound differences. Sometimes they're interchangeable, but mostly they're not. Still: it's your question, if you're happy with it that's fine. I have voted to close, however, due to the lack of clarity, but that's just my opinion. Best of luck.

Comment: @DavidThomas My question has nothing to do with particular code. I am just asking whether there is a CSS attribute that specifies the text color. Why does that have to be accompanied with code to make it clear? I have no idea why you cannot comprehend that.

Answer (score 2):

Like Louis Lazaris said it in April at [sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/12-little-known-css-facts/). The color property isn't just for text. It can change `alt` attribute color, border on list element, bullet and number on list element and hr element color. You can see codepen exemple [here](http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/CtwFG).

Comment: As I wrote in my question, I know that. And you are not answering  my question.

Comment: color is the only way to change color of your text, you need to rewrite your border or wrap your text in a span or any other inline better semantical choice.